0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available
I am trying to deploy a multicontainer application on Minikube and one of my deployments starts, the mariadb one, but the other two get the error message in the title. Since I am new to Kubernetes all help is appreciated. I have the program working with docker compose and used the Kompose tool to create files for kubernetes. And don't worry about the database, this is a personal project, the passwort is currently just for tests.
I added the ui files and the mariadb files.
ui service
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ui
    name: ui
  spec:
    ports:
      - name: "8888"
        port: 8888
        targetPort: 80
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: ui
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}

Ui deployment
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: ui
    name: ui
  spec:
    hostNetwork: false
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        io.kompose.service: ui
    strategy: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.network/docker-compose-rgs-frontend: "true"
          io.kompose.service: ui
      spec:
        containers:
          - image: ui
            name: ui
            ports:
              - containerPort: 80
                hostPort: 8888
                protocol: TCP
            resources: {}
        restartPolicy: Always
  status: {}

Maria db service
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: mariadb
    name: mariadb
  spec:
    ports:
      - name: "3307"
        port: 3307
        targetPort: 3306
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: mariadb
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}


Maria db deployment
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: mariadb
    name: mariadb
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        io.kompose.service: mariadb
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.version: 1.31.2 (a92241f79)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.network/docker-compose-rgs-backend: "true"
          io.kompose.service: mariadb
      spec:
        containers:
          - env:
              - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
                value: rgs
              - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                value: root
            image: mariadb
            name: mariadb
            ports:
              - containerPort: 3306
                hostPort: 3307
                protocol: TCP
            resources: {}
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
                name: db
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
          - name: db
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: db
  status: {}

I tried looking online but I am usure if the solutions like 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports when start the promethus exporter are what I am looking for, I am honest, I don't quite understand it, especially since I didn't define the pod, so I don't know where else i could add the hostNetwork: false value.

The error message means that one of the ports you're defining is already in use by something else. For example, if you have a web server running on your computer on port 80, minikube won't be able to use port 80.

You should almost never have a hostPort: in a Pod spec.  It looks like Kompose might have incorrectly added them to simulate Docker published ports, but in Kubernetes you'd generally use an Ingress object (for HTTP) or a NodePort- or LoadBalancer-type Service.  Does removing the hostPort: settings help?

I tried taking the hostport away, no difference, I get this error message though: Failed to pull image "ui": Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ui, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
But when I check my containers in minikube via docker image ls the containers are available
